# how to check if the object is already created in Django rest framework serializer's to_present function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to check if the object is already created before adding some data to be viewed in the serializer's response.

my code

```py
class AppUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''
    Serializing App User model
    '''
    main_user = MainUserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        '''
        Defining main data for AppUserSerializer
        '''
        model = AppUser
        # fields = "__all__"
        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "mobile",
            "email",
            "birthdate",
            "password",
            "confirm_password",
            "image",
            "main_user",
            "generated_code",
            "user_langauge",
            "dark_mode",
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        '''
        Adds more data to be serialized back with AppUserSerializer
        '''
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        if AppUser.objects.filter().exists(): #need to check if object already there here, what to add inside filter() !!
            if instance.playerprofile_set.all().count() > 0:
                player_profile = instance.playerprofile_set.all()[0]
                data['player_profile'] = PlayerProfileSerializer(
                      player_profile).data
                for item in Team.objects.all():
                    if player_profile in item.players.all():
                        data['team'] = TeamSerializer(item).data
                    if item.cap.id == player_profile.id:
                        data['team'] = TeamSerializer(item).data
        return data
```

Answer (score 1):

If instance has pk it was created.

You could ask
`if instance.pk:`